# Template content doesn't show up after upgrading to Angular 6.1

Tags: angular, meteor

I'm getting as a result of my app.component the name of the template file :
client/imports/app/app.component.html

[Image screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoKrb.png)

Instead of processing my template with its content.

Here's my component code:

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import template from './app.component.html';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template,
})
export class AppComponent {
   user: Meteor.User;

   constructor(private router: Router, zone: NgZone, location:Location) {
    Tracker.autorun(() => {
      if (Meteor.user())
      {
         zone.run(() => {
            this.user = Meteor.user();
         });
      }
      else
      {
        this.user = undefined;
      }
    });
  }

 isMenuActive(value)
 {
    return location.pathname.indexOf(value) !== -1;
 }

 isHome()
 {
    return location.pathname == ""
 }
}
```

Any idea of why it doesn't seem to work anymore?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The usage of the angular meteor compiler package changed a few versions of angular ago. A place to look for info is in the compiler repository itself. There is an example app.

https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/tree/master/examples/MeteorCLI/all-in-one

Basically, you don’t import the template but reference it via templateurl

E.g

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Component` decorator like describe in the [angular component-metadata](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components#component-metadata) documentation.

Write this `import template from './app.component.html';` will be wrong because your template html as no member called *template*.

You may rewrite your decorator instead like this  :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
```

Comment: @billyjoy when I do this, I get an infinite loop on the constructor. I don't really get one.